# Asynchronously checking if email is taken already using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, email, express, mongoose

I have the following email field for taking user input for email. Once the email has been entered and focus is taken away from the field `ng-blur` triggers the function that checks whether the email entered by the user has already been taken:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder=""  ng-model="email" name="email" required ng-blur="isFound(email)">
```

To show the error I've got the following span:

```
<span class="help-block error" ng-show="blurred && isTaken">Email is taken already</span>
```

And here is the function `isFound(email)`:

```
  $scope.isFound = function(email) {
      service.isEmailTaken(email).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data); //this shows either null or the returned data
        $scope.blurred = true;
        if(data == null) {
            $scope.isTaken = false;
        } else {
            $scope.isTaken = true;
        }
      });
  }
```

Now when I try an email that has been taken, it shows the message correctly. But after that even when I enter the email that has not been taken it keeps showing the same message that the `Email is taken already`.

Could somebody help me understand the reason why is it happening and how to resolve it?

**EDIT - Adding AngularJS and NodeJS/ExpressJS/Mongoose code below:**

**AngularJS**

```
factory.isEmailTaken = function(email) {
  return $http({url: "/api/queries/email/" + email, method: "GET"}).then(function(resp) {
      return resp.data;
  });
};
```

**ExpressJS/NodeJS/Mongoose**

```
app.get('/api/queries/email/:email', function (req, res) {
    Query.findOne({email: req.params.email}, function (err, query) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(query);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check that your server is returning the correct data? I don't think anything is wrong with the code that you have posted (except I haven't seen the service code).

Comment: `if(data == null)` ?? Surely you send a response from server

Comment: @DennisRongo: Yes, I get `null` when the email is not taken already and get the proper not null data when the email is taken already. I just have not been able to get this working properly. I don't know what mistake I am committing.

Comment: @charlietfl: Yes, I check the data returned from the server with `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Can you post your Angular service code?

Comment: Add $scope.$apply() at the end.

Comment: @Boland, It gives me `$digest already in progress` when I try that after the `if/else` block. Was I supposed to add it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

When the email was not taken already value of `data` was `null`, and the `typeof data` was `String`.
The reason why it was not working earlier was because `if(data == null)` was always turning out to be `false`.

`if(data == 'null')` got things working properly.